# Evaluating the integral of $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan x}{x}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here, I am calculating $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan x}{x}\,dx$ by parts: $\int_a^b u\,dv=uv|_a^b-\int_a^bv~~du$, in which $ dv=\frac{1}{x},~v=\ln x ,~u=\tan x,~du=\sec^2 x$.

I can derive that $$\tan x\ln x|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln x \sec^2 x\,dx.$$

But I can see that $\tan x$ is not defined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\ln x$ is not defined at $x=0$.

I cannot go further from here. So, I want to evaluate this integral problem. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This integral does not converge.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Thanks @Euler....IS_ALIVE

Answer (score 3):

You have this inequality:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan x}{x} \; dx >\int_1^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan x}{x} \; dx > \int_1^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan x}{\pi/2} \; dx,$$

because on that interval, $x<\pi/2$ so $1/x >2/\pi$. 
This last integral is easily shown to be infinity.

Comment: The first inequality is because $\frac{\tan x}{x} >0$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ so its integral on the subset $(1,\pi/2)$ of $(0,\pi/2)$ is lesser than the integral on $(0,\pi/2)$? The second inequality seems to follow from the fact that $\tan x / x$ is increasing on $(1,\pi/2)$, but how can I prove that is increasing? Thanks.

Comment: The second inequality is because $x>1$ on the interval $(1,\pi/2)$., so $1/x <1$.

Comment: Then the second inequality isn't true, because we should have $\int_1^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan x}{x} \text{d}x \color{red}{<} \int_1^{\pi/2} \tan x \text{d}x$ and so we can't deduce the divergence.
I think that the idea can be saved by considering that $x<\pi/2$ and so $1/x > 2/\pi$ and then $\int_1^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan x}{x} \text{d}x > \frac{2}{\pi} \int_1^{\pi/2} \tan x \text{d}x=\infty$.

Comment: @Dunkelheit  Yep.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}dx$$
we know that:
$$\tan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}\left(2^{2n+2}-1\right)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+1}$$
so we can say that:
$$\int\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n+2}\left(2^{2n+2}-1\right)B_{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n}dx$$
which can easily be solved. However, if you look at the $\tan(\pi/2)$ it diverges to $\infty$n as:
$$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^+}\tan(x)=\infty$$
so for this value the integral is also not defined, and is divergent.